# singly linked list optimally defined over 17 operations in C [2]?

Tags: c, linked-list

## Previous versions of this question

[First Version](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/283167/singly-linked-list-optimized-for-search-insert-in-o1)

[Second Version](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/283203/singly-linked-list-optimally-defined-over-operations-in-c/283208?noredirect=1#comment561781_283208)

## Changes

I added these operations:

- Pop_back
- Pop_front

###### You are not allowed to `insert_sll` at the front or back, but only in position `i` such that `0 < i < n=size-1`.

I also tested the functions, so everything is working!

Thanks in advance for any improvement ideas!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Node {
    int data;
    struct Node* next;
} Node;

Node* head = NULL;
Node* tail = NULL;

Node* create_node(int elm) {
    Node* node = malloc(sizeof * node), *exits = NULL;
    if (!node) return exits;
    node->data = elm;
    node->next = NULL;
    return node;
}

int is_empty_sll() { //O(1)
    return head == NULL;
}

int size_sll() { //O(n) 
    int count = 0;
    Node* last = head;
    while (last) {
        count += 1;
        last = last->next;
    }
    return count;
}

Node* node_k_sll(int k) { // 0-based index
    int n = size_sll() - 1;
    if (!is_empty_sll() && (k >= 0 && k <= n)) {
        int i = 0;
        Node* node = head;
        while (i != k) {
            i += 1;
            node = node->next;
        }
        return node;
    }
    else {
        printf("Out of Index");
        Node* node = NULL;
        return node;
    }
}

void append_sll(int elm) { //O(1)
    Node* cur = create_node(elm);
    if (!head) {
        head = cur;
    }
    else {
        tail->next = cur;
    }
    tail = cur;
}

void prepend_sll(int elm) {
    Node* updated_head = create_node(elm);
    if (!head) {
        head = updated_head;
        tail = head;
    }
    else {
        updated_head->next = head;
        head = updated_head;
    }
}

void insert_sll(int elm, int i) {
    if (!is_empty_sll()) {
        int k = 1, size = size_sll(); // we don't prepend, so K > 0
        Node* cur = create_node(elm);
        if (!head) {
            head = cur;
        }
        else {
            Node* last = head;
            if (i > 1 && i < size) { //  1 < i < size | 1:prepend, n:append
                while (k != i) {
                    k += 1;
                    last = last->next;
                }
                cur->next = last->next;
                last->next = cur;
            }
            else {
                printf("Out of Index");
            }
        }
    }
}

void delete_sll(int elm) {
    int n = size_sll();
    Node* node = head;
    if (head->data == elm) {
        head = head->next;
        free(node);
    }
    else {
        Node* prev = head;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            if (node->data != elm) {
                prev = node;
                node = node->next;
            }
            else {
                break;
            }
        }
        prev->next = node->next;
        free(node);
    }
}

int search_sll(int elm) { //O(n)
    if (!is_empty_sll()) {
        int i, n = size_sll();
        Node* last = head;
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            if (last->data != elm) {
                last = last->next;
            }
            else {
                break;
            }
        }
        return i;
    }
}

void swap_sll(int i, int j) {//O(n) --swap value of position i with j
    Node* node_i = node_k_sll(i);
    Node* node_j = node_k_sll(j);
    int temp = node_i->data;
    node_i->data = node_j->data;
    node_j->data = temp;
}

void print_sll() {
    Node* trav = head;
    while (trav) {
        printf("%d ", trav->data);
        trav = trav->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void reverse_sll() {
    if (!is_empty_sll()) {
        Node* prev = head;
        Node* cur = head->next, * next_node = cur;
        while (next_node) {
            next_node = cur->next;
            cur->next = prev;
            prev = cur;
            cur = next_node;
        }
        head->next = next_node;
        Node* temp = head;
        head = tail;
        tail = temp;
    }
}

//void reverse_sll() {
//    Node* prev = NULL, *cur = head, *next;
//    while (cur) {
//        next = cur->next;
//        cur->next = prev;
//        prev = cur;
//        cur = next;
//    }
//    head = prev;
//    Node* temp = head;
//    head = prev;
//    prev = temp;
//}

void clear_sll() { //O(n)
    while (head) {
        Node* temp = head;
        head = head->next;
        free(temp);
    }
    printf("List Cleared!\n");
}

Node* get_tail() {
    // Node* tail = head;
    // while (tail->next != NULL) {
    //     tail = tail->next;
    // }
    return tail;
}

void rotate_sll(int k) {
    int size = size_sll();
    Node* tail = get_tail();
    Node* k_node = node_k_sll(k);
    tail->next = head;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        printf("%d ", k_node->data);
        k_node = k_node->next;
    }
    tail->next = NULL;
    printf("\n");
}

void pop_front_sll() {
    Node* node = head;
    head = head->next;
    free(node);
}

void pop_back_sll() {
    int size = size_sll();
    int elm = node_k_sll(size - 1)->data;
    delete_sll(elm);
}

// void sort_sll() {// //different algorithms

// }

int main() {
    prepend_sll(-13);
    append_sll(1);
    append_sll(2);
    append_sll(4);
    print_sll();
    insert_sll(3, 2);
    print_sll();
    prepend_sll(0);
    print_sll();
    printf("size: %d\n", size_sll());
    printf("index of 3 is: %d\n", search_sll(3));
    delete_sll(2);
    print_sll();
    swap_sll(0, 1);
    print_sll();
    reverse_sll();
    print_sll();
    append_sll(0);
    append_sll(-1);
    print_sll();
    rotate_sll(2);
    pop_front_sll();
    print_sll();
    pop_back_sll();
    print_sll();
    clear_sll();
    print_sll();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142801/discussion-on-question-by-user21078706-singly-linked-list-optimally-defined-over); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: Please do not edit the question, especially the code, after an answer has been posted. Changing the question may cause answer invalidation. Everyone needs to be able to see what the reviewer was referring to. [What to do after the question has been answered](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: @pacmaninbw yes, I got to know that yesterday. I will post the updated one in a separate question referring to this one.

Comment: We have a tool that spots edits that may invalidate answers, this question showed up just now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What to mention first? I'll start with *interface* taking name decoration (`xyz_sll`) as an indication of trying to create something usable in separate "compilation units".

Interface design is not an easy undertaking.
You can sidestep the issue and implement an existing interface.
With C, the options are somewhat limited:
"Collection" interfaces lend themselves very well to OO modelling.

Interfaces need documentation!
In the code: look how the description for `rotate_sll()` ended up not included in above question.
In C, the definition of an interface belongs in a *header* file.

Tests are valuable. Include them in your questions - where I present a part of the code (for convenience&reference) that I don't want reviewed, I'd state that above and put the code block in a block quote.

If it is nice to have a *list*, it got to be nicer to have more than one:
The global variable `head` doesn't do.
Define a type `List` and pass a value to each and every function but `create_sll()`;

I'm with your choice to not have *nodes* visible on the client side of the interface. It would necessitate more functions and limit implementation choices.
(Keep "global non-client names" to a minimum: declare e.g. `create_node()` & `get_tail()` static. Maybe move `main()` to a separate compilation unit - this would raise the question just where to put "debug support". (Java&Python put some in the main Object contract: `toString()`/`str()`.))

`size_sll()` is "the other function" that would benefit from being kept instead of re-established. The other one is `get_tail()`.

Keeping `tail`up-to-date looks quite a chase without a decent set of (automated!) tests in place:
Currently, `pop_back_sll()` fails to update it.

Keeping `size` instead looks a bit simpler -
and helps `get_tail()` a bit: you can use a "counting loop" instead of checking `next`. You still need to "chase" all those pointers.

There is a *memory leak* in `insert_sll()` when size < `i`.

`delete_sll()` does not check if the node deleted equals `tail`.

(I prefer *find* over *search*.)

---

I see one big problem with the interface so far:
How will a client *use* a list?

Establish *size* and use a (missing) `get_sll(int position)`?
Define a function `apply_while_sll(int *(handler(int item_value))` to call `handler()` with every item's value in turn until it returns false?

Comment: thanks, I will take up your remarks and update the code in another post

Comment: I didn't get that `insert_sll` has a memory leak when size < `i`, I have this if there `if (i > 1 && i < size) ` unless you mean when I want to insert at the place of `tail`, is that what you mean?

Comment: When you print "Out of Index", you have allocated a node. You don't attach it. You don't return it. You don't free() it: It is no longer accessible, its memory is *leaked*.

Comment: you mean it should be like this ```else { free(last); printf("Invalid i");}```

Comment: I'd "instantiate" when `i` checks okay, rather.

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/283243/singly-linked-list-optimally-defined-over-17-operations-in-c-3 [slightly better]

Answer (score 3):

## General Observations

It isn't clear that you understand the usage of singly linked lists, in some cases this looks more like an array implementation than a linked list implementation. Indexing into linked lists is slow and generally not done. The `search_sll()` function returns an index into the linked list rather than a pointer to a node. This really doesn't make sense. Most of the functions that call `Node* node_k_sll(int k)` are not O(n) because they may loop through the list more than one time. The error message `Out of Index` makes no sense in terms of a linked list, and in most cases this should be `Index out of Range`. Generally one doesn't care about the size of a linked list, so the function `int size_sll()` might be considered an [anti-pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-pattern).

Since this code is using Global Variables the code is not reusable than that breaks a lot of programming principles.

The link provided by @DavidC.Rankin is a good reference.

## Unit Testing

The unit testing is insufficient, it doesn't test for behavior on failure. One example is the function `int search_sll(int elm)`, currently if the linked list is empty this function has unknown behavior since there is no `else` clause and no default return value. To test for failure on this function place this line at the beginning of `main()`:

```
printf("index of 3 is: %d\n", search_sll(3));
```

on my computer that function returns 1, I believe that value is incorrect.

## Functions That Don't Make Sense

Since there are no `PUSH` functions the functions `void pop_front_sll()` and `void pop_back_sll()` don't make sense. There would need to be corresponding functions `void push_front_ssl(ARG)` and `void push_back_ssl(ARG)`. I would only expect to see this functions if the linked list was being used to implement a `stack` or a `queue`.

## DRY Code

There is a programming principle called the [Don't Repeat Yourself Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) sometimes referred to as DRY code. If you find yourself repeating the same code multiple times it is better to encapsulate it in a function. If it is possible to loop through the code that can reduce repetition as well.

The functions `void delete_sll(int elm)` and `void insert_sll(int elm, int i)` can be implemented using `search_sll()` function. this would remove the repeated code. There is possibly a bug in `delete_sll()` since it doesn't check to see if the node as found.

## Missing Error Reporting

The function `Node* create_node(int elm)` may terminate the program without informing the user, this is a big problem.

As a side note, while Node* create_node(int elm) uses `EXIT_FAILURE` when the program terminates with error, the `main()` program returns `0` rather than `EXIT_SUCCESS`. *this code was replaced before I posted my answer*

Comment: Thanks, valuable remarks, indeed, I am preparing this list and its doubly version to be used as generically as possible to be used for stacks and queues